# Headers on only first row

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am building a table-view for a website project I have been working on for quite some time and have made some great breakthroughs this past evening. However, an issue that still plagues this system is the headers on every other row of the table-view. Is there anyway to remove the echo for just the headers? I have tried doing so, but it keeps breaking :( http://www.scrimfinder.net

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='style.css?lol=<?php echo time(); ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>


<?php
include_once("dbConnect.php");
if (isset($_GET["frompost"])) {
 echo "<h3>Thank you for your scrim post! It's been tweeted by <a href='http://twitter.com/scrimfinder'>ScrimFinder</a>.";   
 echo "<br>";
} else {
    
}
echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="1">  <tr class="top">  </tr> ';  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scrims ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30;";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
echo '        
<th>System</th>
<th>Region</th>
<th>Game</th>
<th>Match Type</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Time Zone</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Gamertag</th>
<th>Twitter</th>

    <tr>          <td><center>'.$row["system"].'</center></td><td class="grey"><center>'.$row["region"].'</center></td>  <td><center>'.$row["game"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey"><center>'.$row["matchtype"].'</center></td>  <td><center>'.$row["time"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey"><center>'.$row["timezone"].'</center></td>  <td><center>'.$row["date"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey"><center>'.$row["gamertag"].'</center></td>  <td><center><a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$row['twitter'].'" target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="Message '.$row['twitter'].'" class="button"></a></center></td>          </tr>  ';  } echo '</table>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the echo of `heading` outside the loop and echo only `rows` in inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the `th` in your loop that's why its displaying again and again. You should echo your `th` outside of the loop. Something like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href='style.css?lol=<?php echo time(); ?>' rel='stylesheet' 
 type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 include_once("dbConnect.php");
 if (isset($_GET["frompost"])) {
 echo "<h3>Thank you for your scrim post! It's been tweeted by <a 
 href='http://twitter.com/scrimfinder'>ScrimFinder</a>.";   
 echo "<br>";
 } else {
 }
 echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="1"><tr class="top">  
 <th>System</th>
 <th>Region</th>
 <th>Game</th>
 <th>Match Type</th>
 <th>Time</th>
 <th>Time Zone</th>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Gamertag</th>
 <th>Twitter</th>
 </tr>';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM scrims ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30;";  
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 0):
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {    
 echo '        
 <tr><td><center>'.$row["system"].'</center></td><td class="grey">
 <center>'.$row["region"].'</center></td>  <td>
 <center>'.$row["game"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey"> 
 <center>'.$row["matchtype"].'</center></td>  <td>
 <center>'.$row["time"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey">
 <center>'.$row["timezone"].'</center></td>  <td>
 <center>'.$row["date"].'</center></td>  <td class="grey">
 <center>'.$row["gamertag"].'</center></td>  <td><center><a 
 href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$row['twitter'].'" target="_blank"><input 
 type="submit" value="Message '.$row['twitter'].'" class="button"></a>
 </center></td>          </tr>  ';  }
 else:
 echo "<tr><td colspan = '100'>NO RECORDS FOUND</td></tr>";
 endif;
 echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: and what if the query returns empty? Should we get presented with an empty table with only the headers available?

Comment: @NikosGkogkopoulos i've edited my answer to check if returns empty

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to copy all the 'th' tags above while loop so it will render only once.

Answer (score 0):

How should your table look like?

First the header then all content rows? If yes simply place the echo in front of your while-loop

And its important for the TH's that you put them into a TR like normal TD's.